# Flutter save Image in Gallery folder

Tags: flutter

I am currently working on an alert box with the option to take a photo or select a picture from the gallery.

The status so far is:

I can get pictures from the gallery with the ImagePicker, this works perfectly.

Now I come to my problem:

Saving the captured images also works, but it is saved in the storage and therefore not displayed in the gallery. Please help me

Image AlertBox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbRHV.jpg

Image Empty rencent folder
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMfQT.jpg

Made pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lczG6.jpg

Here is the path where the image is stored:

**File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.supportanfrage/files/Pictures/1cd284f4-3632-4ed8-8c6a-14d7be83a8335698897692938961258.jpg'**

Methode for saving images

```
Future getAndSaveImage() async {
    final File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    debugPrint(image.toString());
    if (image == null) return;

    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final String path = directory.path;
    this._fileName = path;
    final File localImage = await image.copy(path);
  }

I using the following dependencies / plugins:

file_picker: ^1.3.8
camera: ^0.5.2+2
image_picker: ^0.6.0+17
image_gallery_saver: ^1.1.0
path_provider: ^1.1.2

Thanks.
```

Comment: you have pasted the method for getImage() not saveImage()

Comment: Im edited the content -> i have also uploaded a picture -> https://imgur.com/a/VIZOTBH

Comment: these are in your galleries, right?

Comment: no, they are stored in the external storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [sample source code](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera) provided for the flutter camera plugin. It will take timeStamp and then save your photo with the name of that timeStampValue.jpg in your phone storage.

```
Future<String> takePicture() async {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return null;
    }
    String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/flutter_test';
    await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
    final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

    if (controller.value.isTakingPicture) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      await controller.takePicture(filePath);
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
    return filePath;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, i inserted your code snippet, but the camera wont start right now.

Comment: I also adding the following lines and added to the initstate(): Future<void> _setupCameras() async {
    try {
      cameras = await availableCameras();
      _cameracontroller =
          new CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
      await _cameracontroller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (_) {}
    if (!_isReady) return;
    setState(() {
      _isReady = true;
    });
  }

Comment: camera won't start right now, means? Have you followed the whole code provided in that link?

Comment: Hey, yes i followed the link and integrated the code into my project

Comment: This seems to save to application's doc folder, which is not the same as the gallery folder on my OnePlus6 unfortunately. So the photos are still out of reach to end users.

Comment: how to save image and video files in gallery? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why is the file still not appearing in the gallery?

On top of accepted answer, if the device is working on Android, you also need to let the device System know that there is a new file with [the media_scanner package](https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner) or create an [adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69016968/images-saved-not-showing-in-gallery-flutter):

```
    final File imageFile = universal_io.File(tmpFullPathName); // file already exists in /tmp.
    final File newFile = universal_io.File(fullPathName);
    await newFile.create(recursive: true);
    await imageFile.copy(fullPathName); // you can of course WriteBytes instead
    if (newFile.existsSync()) {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        MediaScanner.loadMedia(path: fullPathName);
      }
      debugPrint(
          "file successfully moved from cache $tmpFullPathName to $fullPathName");
    }
```

I copy from a file that has already been written to the device with [writeAsBytesSync](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/writeAsBytesSync.html)